# how to change the pagination bullet in a swiper to text?

Tags: jquery, html, frontend, swiper.js, web-frontend

In my project : http://moransh4.github.io/Luca/

I need to change the swiper-pagination-bullet at the last section to this:

[image]

The "active" change to green.

I read ( from : http://idangero.us/swiper/api/) that i can customize with this :

```
 paginationBulletRender: function (index, className) {
        return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
    }
```

Sorry  i go lost with it,

How to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should instead use `paginationCustomRender` to create custom design.Define your `names` in each `div`

```js
var mySwiper2 = new Swiper('.swiper-container.shoes', {
  // Optional parameters
  pagination: '.pag-shoes',
  paginationClickable: true,
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  spaceBetween: 30,
  loop: true,
  paginationType: "custom",
  paginationCustomRender: function(swiper, current, total) {
    var names = [];
    $(".swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide").each(function(i) {
      names.push($(this).data("name"));
    });
    var text = "<span style='background-color:black;padding:20px;'>";
    for (let i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
      if (current == i) {
        text += "<span style='border-top:1px solid green;margin-right:4px;color:green;padding:10px;'>" + names[i] + "</span>";
      } else {
        text += "<span style='border-top:1px solid white;margin-right:4px;color:white;padding:10px;'>" + names[i] + "</span>";
      }

    }
    text += "</span>";
    return text;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://moransh4.github.io/Luca/css/swiper.min.css">
<script src="http://moransh4.github.io/Luca/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container shoes">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-name="LEVEL1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-name="DESIGN">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-name="PERFORMANCE">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide" data-name="DESIGN">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination pag-shoes"></div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next">></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev">
    <</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @GarvitMangal I was looking for this answer. How it can be made clickable? I asked one a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945002/replace-bullet-points-with-specific-string)

Comment: @MainulQuraishi try adding `paginationClickable: true` property in `swiper`